# Good Introductory World History book?

Tags: book

I'm a total novice in humanities and I want to start learning world history. Which do you guys recommend (looking for introductory and didactic books).

Thank's in advance

Comment: +1 I like the question, I started to get interested in History by a timeline book, which never gave enough information, but I could catch interesting parts of history, and research in topics. Sadly I don't remember the book's name anymore.

Comment: Per the [help center](http://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), questions asking for reference material are off-topic here.

Comment: I thought that this would be a question similar to there: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264371/fun-but-serious-mathematics-books-to-gift-advanced-undergraduates and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-mathematician-should-read at least in math.stackexchange it's ok to ask for reference-requests.

Comment: @h3now I think Math.SE is the _only_ SE site that welcomes explicit reference requests. The general policy is that those questions are off topic, but of course every community can bend the rules a bit, if there's very strong support for a certain category of questions.

Comment: Got it! Well you already have one person supporting it =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gonick, Larry.  The Cartoon History of the Universe.  3 vols.  Doubleday.

Gonick, Larry.  The Cartoon History of the United States.  Doubleday.

Gonick, Larry.  The Cartoon History of the Modern World.  2 vols.  Doubleday.

Good bibliography for the time of publication for each issue.  Good methodology and introduction to issues in historiography.  Raises primary sources and their interpretation.  Appropriate speculation.

Comment: Thank you! Seems like what I was looking for...

Also, what do you meant by "Appropriate speculation"?

Comment: Learning to interpolate correctly: http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/8877/what-do-historians-do-when-there-are-no-sources

Comment: Thank you. I'm loving it! Too bad history.stackexchange isn't confortable with reference-requests.